# Http Request reaching late to other microservice

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, httpclient

In my SpringBoot application I am calling other service api with http rest client. One strange behaviour I have traced in my APM that the other service api is getting called at let suppose x sec but it is getting reached to that service at x+5 to x+30 sec range. and that other client process that request in just ms. so overall response time is something between x+5 to x+30 sec. I have also increased the max connection per route(It is configurable through env variable) but nothing worked. I am using PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager in my service to create HttpClient. Any suggestions/help will be appreciated.

Comment: How big have you configured the pool?

Comment: Whats is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Perhaps turn on HttpClient logging to see what is happening under the covers - sometimes DNS requests can slow things up .. (are you using HTTPS or HTTP?)?

Comment: HTTP_MAX_PER_ROUTE: "25"
HTTP_POOL_SIZE: "200"
and connection manager i have used is PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager

Comment: @MrR I am using http

Comment: Have you tried doing the same thing from the command line - perhaps the service is slow / intermittent?? [always good to eliminiate other things]?

Comment: With terminal it is working normal. Is there any request queuing at other side because traffic on other service is high. Is there any way to check the internal communication done by http client. Can we generate any http logs?